# How to combine the results of spark computations in the following case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The question is to calculate average of each of the columns corresponding to each class. Class number is given in the first column.

I am giving a part of test file for better clarity.

```
2 0.819039 -0.408442 0.120827
3 -0.063763 0.060122 0.250393
4 -0.304877 0.379067 0.092391
5 -0.168923 0.044400 0.074417
1 0.053700 -0.088746 0.228501
2 0.196758 0.035607 0.008134
3 0.006971 -0.096478 0.123718
4 0.084281 0.278343 -0.350414
```

So the task is to calculate

```
1: avg(), avg(), avg()
.
.
.
```

I am very new to Scala. After juggling a lot with the code I came up with the following code

```
val inputfile = sc.textFile ("testfile.txt")
val myArray = inputfile.map { line =>
    (line.split(" ").toList)
}
var Avgmap:Map[String,List[Double]] = Map()
var countmap:Map[String,Int] = Map()
for( a <- myArray ){
    //println( "Value of a: " + a + " " + a.size );
    if(!countmap.contains(a(0))){
        countmap += (a(0) -> 0)
        Avgmap += (a(0) -> List.fill(a.size-1)(1.0))
    }
    var c = countmap(a(0)) + 1
    val countmap2 = countmap + (a(0) -> c)
    countmap = countmap2

    var p = List[Double]()
    for( i <- 1 to a.size - 1) {
        var temp = (Avgmap(a(0))(i-1)*(countmap(a(0)) - 1) + a(i).toDouble)/countmap(a(0))
        // println("i: "+i+" temp: "+temp)
        var q = p :+ temp
        p = q
    } 
    val Avgmap2 = Avgmap + (a(0) -> p)
    Avgmap = Avgmap2;
    println("--------------------------------------------------")
    println(countmap)
    println(Avgmap)
}
```

When I execute this code I seem to be getting the results in two halves of the dataset. Please help me in combining them.

Edit: About the variables I am using. `countmap` keeps record of `classnumber -> number of vectors encountered`. Similarly `Avgmap` keeps record of average so far of each columns corresponding to the key.

Comment: You are working with spark, that means your data and calculations are working across a distributed cluster.  This means you have to write your code differently than if you were just running calculations locally.  You can't update some external collection within your calculations.  Everything needs to happen inside the rdd.  Take a look at the spark api.  You'l want to group by your class type and then use an aggregate to calculate your average.  It may be easier if you go with spark sql and dataframes as well.

Answer (score 0):

at first, use DataFrame API. at secont, what you want is just one row

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => mean(col(c))) :_*).show
```